# how do i clear a draw uiview?

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, drawing, draw

I am currently trying to refresh or clear my `UIView` draw but a lot of methods aren't working.  I tried:

1. `self.Draw.clearsContextBeforeDrawing`
2. `[self.Draw setNeedsDisplay];`
3. `self.Draw.removeFromSuperview;`

My code:

```
-(void)drawPoint:(UITouch *)touch 
{

    PointLocation *currentLoc = [[PointLocation alloc] init];

    currentLoc.location = [touch locationInView:self];

    self.previousPoint = self.point;

    self.point = currentLoc;
    [self drawToBuffer];

    [self setNeedsDisplay];
}
```

Is there any way to clear my uidraw? Or at least reload it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a few basic problems here.

How is Draw declared?  Follow cocoa naming conventions.  Only Class names should be capitalized.  Instances of a class should start with a lowercase letter.

I think what you want is:

```
@interface Draw: UIView
@end

@implementation Draw

- (void) drawRect: (CGRect) r {
  // here you will draw whatever you want in your view.
}

@end

Draw* draw;
```

in your drawPoint method:

```
[draw setNeedsDisplay];
```

For more details see The View Drawing Cycle:
http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006816-CH3-SW136

For bonus points, name your view something more descriptive than Draw.  It is a view of something, a window containing some content.  It is not a verb.

Comment: its 

{CGImageRef cgImage = CGBitmapContextCreateImage(offScreenBuffer);
    UIImage *uiImage = [[UIImage alloc] initWithCGImage:cgImage];
    
    CGImageRelease(cgImage);
    
    [undoManager beginUndoGrouping];
    
    [uiImage drawInRect:self.bounds];}